# Does VSCode have a built in MarkdownString to HTML function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I'm working on a custom VSCode extension for a proprietary language. I've created a new Activity Bar option and added a `WebviewView` to it. Within this new `WebviewView` I'd like to display some documentation for various language commands that we have. The documentation has been added to a javascript file and the text within the strings has been pre-formatted using Markdown which works perfectly with the inbuilt auto-complete (`CompletionItemProvider`) and the hover functionality (`HoverProvider`).

I'd like to be able to use the existing documentation, however the view only supports HTML and I haven't been able to find a way to convert the text to HTML or get the `MarkdownString` to conver to HTML using standard VSCode functionality.

Via search, the only suggestion I've found so far is to install a 3rd party extension to get such functionality. Is this really the only solution? Surely there must be some internal function/method to convert the MarkdownString to HTML, VSCode does it somehow, right?

Comment: VSC also uses a 3rd party module to do the conversion, but they might not have exposed it in the API so just install one that does the job with `npm`